# How to copy the last observation's value to other observations in panel data in Stata?

Tags: stata

I have a list of different companies over different time periods. 
During the study time, companies change industries. 
I want to keep only the last industry value for all years for each company in my data.
Can anybody please help me how to do it in Stata?
Example:

Current Data

```
Time    Company Industry
---------------------------
1       A       Agriculture
2       A       Agriculture
3       A       Mining 
1       B       Service sector
2       B       Service sector
3       B       Agriculture
4       B       Agriculture
5       B       Other
```

Desired Data

```
Time    Company Industry
---------------------------
1       A       Agriculture
2       A       Agriculture
3       A       Agriculture
1       B       Other
2       B       Other
3       B       Other
4       B       Other
5       B       Other
```

Comment: Whether panels are balanced or not doesn't affect the answer here. I edited that out of the title.

Answer (score 0):

You should install `dataex` using

```
ssc install dataex
```

to get a command that provides data examples for people answering Stata questions. Otherwise examples like yours require surgery to be made easy to use.

The main device here to use sorting, `by:` and subscripts to select the last observation in each group. Under `by:` the subscript `_N` is always associated with the last observation.

```
clear 
input Time str1 Company str14 Industry
1       A       "Agriculture"
2       A       "Agriculture"
3       A       "Mining" 
1       B       "Service sector"
2       B       "Service sector"
3       B       "Agriculture"
4       B       "Agriculture"
5       B       "Other"
end 

bysort Company (Time): gen Final = Industry[_N] 

list, sepby(Company) 


     +-----------------------------------------+
     | Time   Company        Industry    Final |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  1. |    1         A      Agriculture  Mining |
  2. |    2         A      Agriculture  Mining |
  3. |    3         A           Mining  Mining |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  4. |    1         B   Service sector   Other |
  5. |    2         B   Service sector   Other |
  6. |    3         B      Agriculture   Other |
  7. |    4         B      Agriculture   Other |
  8. |    5         B            Other   Other |
     +-----------------------------------------+
```

See the help for `by:` for an introduction; then the manual entry `[D] by`; and then its references.

I created a new variable, which is generally a better idea for data management.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. when I applied it on the character variable, it didn't give the correct results. However when I convert into factor and applied the code which you provided. I am able to get the results. 
Again Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Code you don't show on data you don't supply not giving correct results: I can't help you there. Otherwise good that this helped.